# How to ensure that parent is passing populated props to a child component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Good day all. Imagine we have a parent and a child component i.e `PracticePersonLists` (parent) -> `BCardHeaderWithButton` (child). Now the child consists of a `vue-multiselect` like so where `leftAction` is an Object prop

```
<!-- Multiselect -->
<multiselect
  v-if="leftAction.type === 'options'"
  v-model="leftAction.model"
  :options="leftAction.options"
  :placeholder="leftAction.placeholder"
  :searchable="true"
  :show-labels="true"
  :allow-empty="false"
/>
```

The parent renders the child like so:

```
<b-card-header-with-button
  v-if="(isHR && (person.md_current === 1))"
  card-title="Events"
  :left-action="eventsLeftAction"
  :right-action="eventsRightAction"
  @rightActionClick="addEvent()"
/>
```

`eventsLeftAction` is a data property inside the parent looking like so:

```
eventsLeftAction: {
  show: true,
  type: 'options',
  options: this.eventsFilters,
  model: this.compEventsLeftActionModel,
  placeholder: 'Select Event'
}
```

`eventsFilters` is generated in the `created` hook of the parent

`this.eventsFilters = await buildNonBackEndFilterOptions(this.events, 'eventHead', 'eventGroup')`

but the problem is that on page load , the child component cannot find its `leftAction.options` so it comes back as undefined. We think it is something connected with the fact that child components get rendered before parent, hence it is looking for data that doesn't exist yet.... usually we overcome this by setting a `dataLoaded` Boolean and render the child only if the Boolean is true but it doesn't seem to work in this case

Would anybody know how to overcome this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not true. parent `created` called before child rendered.
the problem in you code is

```
eventsLeftAction: {
  show: true,
  type: 'options',
  options: this.eventsFilters,
  model: this.compEventsLeftActionModel,
  placeholder: 'Select Event'
}
```

you cannot set `option:this.eventsFilters` the use of `this` is not valid here at all.

you should do it like this

```
eventsLeftAction: {
  show: true,
  type: 'options',
  options: null,
  model: null,
  placeholder: 'Select Event'
}
```

and in the `created` hook set the values

```
async created(){
    //you can here whatever you want. its called before child rendered
    this.eventsLeftAction.options= await buildNonBackEndFilterOptions(this.events, 
        'eventHead', 'eventGroup')
}
```

Comment: This worked like mint! You are an absolute ledge, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The only solution we could come up for now is to store the options in Vuex from the `created` hook of the parent and then pull them with `mapState` in the child.

Parent:

```
this.eventsFilters = await buildNonBackEndFilterOptions(this.events, 'eventHead', 'eventGroup')
this.setPracticePersonListsEventsFilters(this.eventsFilters)

methods: {
    ...mapMutations('practice', ['setPracticePersonListsEventsFilters']),
}
```

Child:

```
<multiselect
  v-if="leftAction.type === 'options'"
  v-model="leftAction.model"
  :options="compOptions"
  :placeholder="leftAction.placeholder"
  :searchable="true"
  :show-labels="true"
  :allow-empty="false"
/>

computed: {
  ...mapState('practice', ['practicePersonListsEventsOptions']),
  compOptions () {
    switch (this.$route.name) {
      case 'app.practice.person.lists':
        return this.practicePersonListsEventsOptions
      default:
        return ''
    }
  }
}
```

If anybody knows a better solution, we would appreciate if you share.